# View the products of the logged-in user

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Symfony : 6.1.4
EasyAdmin :4.3.5

I try to display the products created by the logged in user. By default, all products are displayed regardless of the author.

ProductCrudController.php

```
class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Product::class;
    }
    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        $response = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
        $response->andWhere('entity.creator = :creator')->setParameter('creator', ???????);
        return $response;
    }

[...]

}
```

Problem : I need to get the id of the user who created the product.

But I can't get it back via $_SESSION :

[image]

```
{{dump(app.user)}}
```

[image]

One solution I can think of is to use app.user.id in ProductCrudController.php but it is a php file. Do you have any leads to achieve this or other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `$this->getUser()` in your controller and retrieve the current logged in user and use it to filter your products.

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    return parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters)
        ->andWhere('entity.creator = :creator')
        ->setParameter('creator', $this->getUser());
}
```